# dataTaskWithURL sometimes no return

Tags: swift, ios8, nsurlsession

I have a very simple http request which will return a JSON data. Here is my code:

```
        let query = NSString(format: "http://glosbe.com/gapi/translate?from=eng&dest=eng&format=json&phrase=test",src, dest, phrase )
        let url = NSURL(string: query)

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) {(data, response, error) in
            if let httpRes = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                println("status code=",httpRes.statusCode)
                if httpRes.statusCode == 200 {
                    println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
                    // parse data
                    let phrase = Phrase.parse(data)
                    println(phrase.description)
                }
            }
        }

        task.resume()
```

Sometimes the completionHandler isn't called at all. I suspect it's the problem of the server. But when I input the same url into my browser and tried a dozens times. There was no problem at all. The data was returned everything when I refresh the browser.

Is there anything wrong in my code? Thanks

Comment: it looks ok to me I must say -- is this for an app thats in foreground or background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works OK for me. I suggest you can make this change to your code (an `else` clause):

```
        if let httpRes = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
            println("status code=",httpRes.statusCode)
            if httpRes.statusCode == 200 {
                println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
                // parse data
                let phrase = Phrase.parse(data)
                println(phrase.description)
            }
        } else { 
            println("error \(error)") // print the error!
        }
```

So you will have a better idea if anything goes wrong